# Best data structure in C# for finding maximal value?

Tags: c#, data-structures, find, element, max

I need to know which is the best data structure for finding a maximal value and is it implemented in C#? For now I'm using SortedDictioniry but it sorts the keys and basically I don't need the keys to be sorted but what I need is a faster way to find the maximal value. Also after I find the maximal value I need the key or the index corresponding to this value. Also if it is possible to have a quick insertion and quick removal of the elements, hopefully not more than O(log n). Is there such a structure and how can I use it?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information?  I assume that the insertions are done outside of your control, so you can't simply get the maximal value as it's inserted?

Comment: Having trouble with your homework? Show us the code.

Comment: How about [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxb97few.aspx)?

Comment: You may be reading too much into a name.  The "key" used by a SortedDictionary need only be unique, but it can be any value that has meaning to you, e.g. the value for which you are seeking the maximum value.  The corresponding "value" in the dictionary, similarly, is just data.  If it happens to be a key used elsewhere, e.g. a database table, so be it.

Comment: @user1161318 - I am using nested loops for insertion of the elements which means there are many elements that are inserted and that's why I need something which is fast.

Comment: @IronMan84 - It's not a homework, it's something more like a project but I think that for now I can't give you much code.

Comment: @HABO - There can be equal values which is why I can't use SortedDictionary - just as you said the key has to be unique and the values in my case are not.

Comment: @D Stanley - SortedList I think wont help me because as far as I understood it is sorting the elements by key and not by value.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds just like a [max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), there's plenty of on-line information on how to implement one from scratch (it isn't part of C# standard data structures).

For instance, take a look at this [implementation](https://chinmaylokesh.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/c-binary-max-heap-implementation/), complete with a detailed explanation.

Comment: I agree, with a heap you get a O(1) in query-ing your maximum value, with a O(log n) on insertion and deletion.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at the solution you gave me. I thought that there could be an already implemented structure in C# but it looks like that I have to implement it manually.

Comment: @SimeonNikolov you're welcome! If this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left :)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient will be max-heap, as previously stated. It is not a part of .Net, but you can choose from 3rd party libraries, like [IntervalHeap](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.IntervalHeap%601.htm) (from http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/)

Comment: Thanks, I will look at the library you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or a [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (as you already do). Another suitable collection type would be the Max-Heap; however, the .NET class library does not include one.

See also [SortedList and SortedDictionary Collection Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for a comparison on MSDN. Also I don't see another possibility than sorting in some way by the key, if you want too have a fast access time on the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 6, the most suitable data structure for this scenario is probably the [`PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) class. This container supports only the operations `Enqueue`, `Dequeue` and `Peek`, with the smaller priority elements dequeued first. Elements with equal priority are dequeued with undefined order. To make it deque first the elements with the largest priority you need to supply it with a custom [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1), like the one below:

```
class ReverseComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    public int Compare(T x, T y) => -Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x, y);
}
```

Usage example, with priority of type `int` and elements of type `string`:

```
var queue = new PriorityQueue<string, int>(new ReverseComparer<int>());
queue.Enqueue("Red", 10);
queue.Enqueue("Green", 20);
queue.Enqueue("Yellow", 15);
queue.Enqueue("Brown", 25);
queue.Enqueue("Purple", 20);
while (queue.TryDequeue(out var element, out var priority))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{priority} -> {element}");
}
```

Output:

```
25 -> Brown
20 -> Purple
20 -> Green
15 -> Yellow
10 -> Red
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t6pgsQ).